# jaspersoft studio display horizontal list

Tags: sqlite, jasper-reports

I'm using Jaspersoft and I have used the list component in my report. I have a problem when I try to fill it. I would like to choose the option to print horizontally, but when I print the list, the items are still printed vertically.
How it works:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1Lnd.png)

I would like it : analyse1  analyse2  analyse7

Comment: You should post the small *jrxml* to reproduce the problem

Comment: i m working with jaspersoft and i linked it with sqlite database & this is My Source Code :
http://pastebin.com/4PwpMv6j

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to report properties.
2. Change print order vertical to horizontal.
3. Set columns to 15 or whatever you want.

Comment: .i've experimented with this

But the result did not change